# Center text horizontally and vertically in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working on a C# Silverlight application that needs some text rotated 90 degrees CCW and for it to be center within an image that is 100px x 221px.  The rotation part was easy to do in the design view, but centering the text has been a nightmare.  (I am using a 16px font that cant be changed or resized)

My text is dynamic and can be one or two lines.  When it is two lines long I can center it fine...but if It is only one line long, I cannot center it.  The only way to center it so far is to resize the box and move it to the right.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f0435a8c65.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f0435a8c65.png)

Comment: Want to post some XAML? It's hard to diagnose what you need to do without seeing what you are currently trying to do...

Comment: Thank you for repling.  I was able to figure it out on my own.  See below for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="Background" Source="Background.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Title"
        Margin="-19.75,68.25,-21.25,67.806" Text="Here is some text to fill this up"
        Foreground="#FF00A33D"
        FontSize="22" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto"
        TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"
    >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Then in the cs file set the alignment when you change the text

```
Title.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```